Terraform Snowflake: create a database without public schema
When I create a Snowflake table with the database resource it will automatically create a schema PUBLIC.
How can I prevent this behaviour?
resource "snowflake_database" "simple" {
  name                        = "testing"
  comment                     = "test comment"
  data_retention_time_in_days = 3
}


You can't stop the PUBLIC schema being created. You can subsequently drop it - but why do you care? What difference does it make if there's a PUBLIC schema in your database?

A database will be created with the PUBLIC schema by default.
By default, all users have access to this schema. You can restrict access using REVOKE.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/revoke-privilege
